# camel header with message number

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-camel, load-balancing

With Apache Camel I want to send to rabbitmq exchange messages with different routing keys for load balancing(now i have exchange with 4 routing keys, more in the future). Is there an easy way to add different headers(routing keys  .setHeader("rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY", envelope.getRoutingKey()); ) to messages?

**UPDATED:**

I solved problem with processors and ${id}:

```
.setHeader("id", simple("${id}"))
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    String id = exchange.getIn().getHeader("id").toString();
    String newRoutingKey = ROUTING_KEY_PREFIX +
            (Integer.valueOf(id.split(":")[MESSAGE_NUMBER_IND]) % ROUTING_KEYS_NUMBER);
    exchange.getIn().removeHeader("id");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("rabbitmq.ROUTING_KEY", newRoutingKey);
} }).to(rmqQueue)
```

Is there any hidden problems?

Answer (score 1):

You can use toD to set the routing keys dynamically to an RabbitMq endpoint.

XML Syntax:

> `<toD uri="rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?routingKey=**${header.routekey}**"/>`

where header.routekey is the dynamic key you intend to use and it is set in the header.

In case of Java DSL, the syntax might look like:

> .toD("rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?routingKey=**${header.routekey}**");

Comment: The problem is that i have to use custom class (RMQEndpoint extends DefaultEndpoint). I'm not be able to change it easily. Is there any other way to set routing key by changing headers?

Comment: are you not using the rabbitmq component?

Comment: Then I assume that you can using the rabbitmq Component the RMQEndpoint impl.  There are two options here. Can you change the RMQEndpoint to extend RabbitMQEndpoint instead of Default Endpoint?  If you can publish some code snippets of your route and Endpoint, we can help you better.